# How to apply a custom comparator to an R dataframe?

Tags: r

In R I need to apply a custom function to grouped rows of a dataframe to obtain a filtered dataframe.
The function should take as input two rows and return, based on a custom comparator, one or the other. At the end I want a dataframe that is made of all the collected remaining rows.

Here is my attempt:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = c(40, 37, 60, 45), c = c('foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'))


> df
  a  b      c
1 1 40    foo
2 2 37    foo
3 3 60    bar
4 4 45    bar

get_one <- function(pair) {
  
  first = pair[1,] 
  second = pair[2,]
  
  # TODO: custom comparator

  return(second) # for now
}

new_df <- df %>% group_by(c) %>% group_map(~ get_one(pair = .x))
```

**This returns a list of tibbles, not a dataframe.
How do I transform this list of tibbles in a dataframe?**

Expected result:

```
> new_df
  a  b      c
2 2 37    foo
4 4 45    bar
```

Comment: Please explain the logic what `get_one` function is supposed to do. Why row 2 and 4 are returned?

Comment: Because in this prototype I have omitted the code for the comparator and the function is just returning the second row.

Comment: What is comparator? How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: The custom comparator will sort the two rows based on some conditions and the function will return, let's say, the last one. My question is, once this function returns a row for each of the groups, how do I collect them all into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `bind_rows` to your current attempt :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(c) %>% 
  group_map(~ get_one(pair = .x)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

---

Couple of other approaches :

Using nesting and unnesting :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(c) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, get_one)) %>%
  unnest(data)

# c         a     b
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 foo       2    37
#2 bar       4    45
```

Using `cur_data()` :

```
df %>%  group_by(c) %>% summarise(data = get_one(cur_data()))
```